# Routes for controllers in subfolders

Tags: yii2

In my Yii2 project I'm trying to user the following directory structure to organize my controllers:

```
/controllers/ReportController.php
/controllers/report/Report1Controller.php
/controllers/report/Report2Controller.php
/controllers/report/Report3Controller.php
```

with namespaces as

```
app\controllers
app\controllers\report
app\controllers\report
app\controllers\report
```

All controllers contain a

```
public function actionIndex()
```

function.

When I access the URL

```
https://myreporting.test/report
```

it properly routes to

```
controllers/ReportController.php - actionIndex()
```

Whenever I try to access the URL

```
https://myreporting.test/report/report1
```

it returns a 404 error instead of routing to

```
controllers/report/Report1Controller.php - actionIndex()
```

How can I achieve that the framework properly routes to the index actions of the controllers in the subdirectories? The main ReportController is not containing any actions with conflicting names.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set url manager to recognize routes like that. You can do that in your web.php config. For example:

```php
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => \yii\web\UrlManager::class,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'report/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:(\d|\w)+>' => 'report/<controller>/<action>',
            'report/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => 'report/<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:(\d|\w)+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ],
    ],
    // ... other components ...
].
// ... other configurations ...
```

You can also set the folder part dynamically for example using rule like this

```php
'<folder:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<folder>/<controller>/<action>'
```

But I wouldn't recommend that because similar pattern is used for modules.